# retiring a facebook page tab application

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-page, facebook-apps

I have a Facebook Application that installs on users' Page tabs. I would like to retire the application. Does anyone know what will happen if I remove the page tab url from my app? Will it remove the tabs from our users' Facebook Pages? Or will it leave them with broken links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete the app from the developer app, it removes the app from the fan pages.
If you only stop serving the canvas page, but keep the app active on facebook, it breaks. I just tested this with an app today, 2012-12-15.

Comment: Ah, I definitely don't want to delete the app since I want to keep the "Facebook Connect" functionality on my site. I just want to retire the tabs... I guess there's no graceful way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you for checking though!

Comment: You can set a different page for the tab page, and on that page place a notice to users that you will be discontinuing the tab app on a date, and provide contact info. Then on that date, take it down.